# Salesforce Integration with External System

Tags: integration, oauth2

I'm trying to develop an "oauth" integration for an app to be included on appexchange. Based on other applications that use the same protocol, I could not figure out where the "client id" is taken which is passed in url for the call used to get the token. Obviously it can not be static because the app should be installed from anyone. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: So - your question is where you should get your "client id" from? Like how it gets passed from the org of your customer to your app? Is that correct?

Comment: yes it is correct

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same challenge. You can just create a public list custom setting so your customer is able to set these values. Then create the needed fields for your specific OAuth grant type (client id and client secret if you're using the OAuth client credential grant as I do).

Comment: And you probably also need another custom setting to manage your OAuth access tokens. (This one should be protected.)

Comment: for example, the Box connector for Salesforce uses an oauth protocol. When I configure the settings to connect the environment, the client id is passed in url, but  I have not set it anywhere :(

Comment: I'm super confused. Are you using the Box connector as an example or is it part of your integration? And the client id for what is passed in an url?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the oauth protocol works to make salesforce communicate with an external application (take data from the outside) and I used box connector as an example to understand how the two systems interfaced

Comment: You need to know the OAuth grant type you're going to use so you know what fields you actually need to put into your setting. I updated my answer accordingly.